I'm trying to create a responsive site but when I increase the size of the input fields it doesn't increase or become responsive
I have this login screen and I'm developing the registration screen, but I can't increase the size of my inputs so that they are the same as or close to the login screen.
login screen Login screen The code for the registration screen that I have developed so far is as follows
cadastro.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cadastro - Tradlibras</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cadastro.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="Js/redirecionamento.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fundo">
        <h1 id="bem_vindo">Cadastrar-se</h1>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Digite o seu nome" class="inputs">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Digite seu email" class="inputs">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Digite sua Senha" class="inputs">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Digite sua Senha novamente" class="inputs">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check_termos">
            <label for="check_termos" id="text_termos">Você aceita os <a href="#" id="termos_de_uso">termos de uso</a></label>
        </div>
        <div id="botao_cadastrar_container">
            <button onclick="mudar_pagina('./index.html')" type="button" class="botoes">Cadastrar novo Usuário</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

cadastro.css
body {
  background-image: url('../img/Bem vindo ao Tradlibras.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.fundo {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 30px; /* Ajustado para combinar com o padding do login */
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 600px; /* Ajustado para combinar com o max-width do login */
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.fundo h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em; /* Ajustado para combinar com o font-size do login */
  margin-bottom: 20px; /* Ajustado para combinar com o margin-bottom do login */
}

.fundo input[type="text"], 
.fundo input[type="email"], 
.fundo input[type="password"] {
  width: 90%; /* Ajustado para combinar com a largura dos inputs do login */
  padding: 10px; /* Ajustado para combinar com o padding dos inputs do login */
  margin: 10px 0; /* Ajustado para combinar com a margin dos inputs do login */
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em; /* Ajustado para combinar com o font-size dos inputs do login */
}

#text_termos {
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.9em; /* Ajustado para combinar com o font-size do link "Esqueci a senha" */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#termos_de_uso {
  color: #1a73e8; /* Cor do link para termos de uso */
  text-decoration: none;
}

#botao_cadastrar_container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.botoes {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 300px; /* Ajustado para combinar com o max-width do botão do login */
  padding: 10px; /* Ajustado para combinar com o padding do botão do login */
  border: none;
  background-color: #1a73e8;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em; /* Ajustado para combinar com o font-size do botão do login */
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.botoes:hover {
  background-color: #155cb0;
}

::placeholder {
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Responsividade */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .fundo {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
  }

  #Txt_login {
    font-size: 2em;
  }

  #btn_telaLogin_cadastrar {
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #Txt_login {
    font-size: 1.8em;
  }

  #botao_login {
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 1em;
  }

  #btn_telaLogin_cadastrar {
    padding: 8px 15px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }
}


and I'm trying to make it fully responsive, maybe that's why it's preventing me from increasing the inputs for some reason.

Add the following to the .fundo class:
align-items: stretch


body {
    background-image: url('../img/Bem vindo ao Tradlibras.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  
  .fundo {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 30px; /* Ajustado para combinar com o padding do login */
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 600px; /* Ajustado para combinar com o max-width do login */
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .fundo h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em; /* Ajustado para combinar com o font-size do login */
    margin-bottom: 20px; /* Ajustado para combinar com o margin-bottom do login */
  }
  
  .fundo input[type="text"], 
  .fundo input[type="email"], 
  .fundo input[type="password"] {
    width: 90%; /* Ajustado para combinar com a largura dos inputs do login */
    padding: 10px; /* Ajustado para combinar com o padding dos inputs do login */
    margin: 10px 0; /* Ajustado para combinar com a margin dos inputs do login */
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em; /* Ajustado para combinar com o font-size dos inputs do login */
  }
  
  #text_termos {
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.9em; /* Ajustado para combinar com o font-size do link "Esqueci a senha" */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  #termos_de_uso {
    color: #1a73e8; /* Cor do link para termos de uso */
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  #botao_cadastrar_container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  .botoes {
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 300px; /* Ajustado para combinar com o max-width do botão do login */
    padding: 10px; /* Ajustado para combinar com o padding do botão do login */
    border: none;
    background-color: #1a73e8;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em; /* Ajustado para combinar com o font-size do botão do login */
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .botoes:hover {
    background-color: #155cb0;
  }
  
  ::placeholder {
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  /* Responsividade */
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .fundo {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 20px;
      border-radius: 15px;
    }
  
    #Txt_login {
      font-size: 2em;
    }
  
    #btn_telaLogin_cadastrar {
      top: 10px;
      right: 10px;
    }
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
    #Txt_login {
      font-size: 1.8em;
    }
  
    #botao_login {
      width: 80%;
      font-size: 1em;
    }
  
    #btn_telaLogin_cadastrar {
      padding: 8px 15px;
      font-size: 0.9em;
    }
  }
<body>
    <div class="fundo">
        <h1 id="bem_vindo">Cadastrar-se</h1>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Digite o seu nome" class="inputs">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Digite seu email" class="inputs">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Digite sua Senha" class="inputs">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Digite sua Senha novamente" class="inputs">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check_termos">
            <label for="check_termos" id="text_termos">Você aceita os <a href="#" id="termos_de_uso">termos de
                    uso</a></label>
        </div>
        <div id="botao_cadastrar_container">
            <button onclick="mudar_pagina('./index.html')" type="button" class="botoes">Cadastrar novo Usuário</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>



